# How to deploy .so file during application installation

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I am currently working on an android application which is using a shared library (.so) file.

During my development I pushed the .so with the help of ADB (adb push command) and everything is working pretty well !

Now I am wondering how can I deploy this .so file during an user application installation (for example Google Play deployement (even if there are a lots of thing before this step !)).

Thank you by advance for your advice.

Regards,

Joze

Comment: Try including it in `/libs/armeabi/` in project.

Answer (score -1):

You could, probably, use PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY target, see your-ndk\docs\PREBUILTS.html